# Have a relatively complex form and submission process. Need help on slimming it down

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am working on a personal project which is a website that allows users to document there drug usage. The goal of this is for users to be able to quickly reference when the last time they ingested X, and other similar statistics.

Users also store dosages, and units that the dose is measured. And this is where the problem is. In my database I have every unit of measurement associated with a conversion value. The plan was to have this conversion value so that every dose stored would be easy to mold and use when creating things such as graphs.

For example, a gram has a conversion value of 1, while a mg has .001.

Which means if a user enters that he took 1 Gram of X, this data goes through my form submission function, multiple the 1 Gram by the conversion value (1) and stores the final product (1) in the db.

Similarily, if a user enters he took 300 Milligrams of X, the 300 is multiplied by .001 to get 0.3.

Having a system like this allows me to easily add both values and get "1.3 Grams of X taken"

I am not experienced with these kind of complex things, and when I coded this into the site it was a temporary fix, which is very sloppy. Now I know I need to figure out a way better method in storing this.

Below I will add the code that renders the form, and the code that processes the form.

Form:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('Record.dose_date', array('placeholder' => 'Date of Dose', 'label' => false,'type' => 'text','id' =>'datepicker'));    
    echo $this->Form->input('RecordDrugUnit.drug_id', array('placeholder' => 'Substance', 'options'=>$drugList,'label' => false,'type' => 'select')); 
    echo $this->Form->input('RecordDrugUnit.dose', array('placeholder' => 'Dose', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'colLarge left')); 
    echo $this->Form->input('RecordDrugUnit.unit_id', array('placeholder'=>'Unit', 'options'=>$unitList, 'label' => false,'type'=>'select', 'class' => 'colSmall right')); 
    echo $this->Form->submit('SUBMIT', array('class' => 'button')); 
    echo $this->Form->input('RecordDrugUnit.route_id', array('placeholder'=>'Unit', 'options'=>$routeList, 'label' => false,'type'=>'select', 'class' => 'colLarge right'));
    echo $this->Form->input('Record.title', array('placeholder' => 'Title', 'label' => false,'type' => 'text'));
    echo $this->Form->input('Record.report', array('placeholder' => 'Your Report','label' => false,'type' => 'textarea')); 
?>
```

Controller:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->Record->create();
    $conv_val = $this->Unit->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'id' => $this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['unit_id']),
        'fields' => array('conversion')
    ));
    $this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['dose'] = (float)$this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['dose'] * (float)$conv_val['Unit']['conversion'];
    $this->request->data['Record']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
   if ($this->RecordDrugUnit->saveAssociated($this->request->data, array('deep' => TRUE))) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your post.');
    }
}
```

Looking for suggestions on how to simplify this

Answer (score 0):

I think storing the conversions in a table is unnecessary, since it's not likely units will ever change.  You could make your form have a "unit" pulldown instead, with hardcoded options `array('1' => 'grams', '.001' => 'milligrams', etc.,)`, then dose will equal `(float)$this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['dose'] * (float)$this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['unit'];`